# Can you inline static member functions?

Tags: c++, inline, static-methods

I have a static member function which is merely syntactic sugar for me and I would like its body to appear in place of going through the motions of passing parameters to it. Will

```
inline static foo(int a) {return a & 0x00000040;}
```

be inlined just as it would if it was `inline` without being `static`?

Comment: As with any inlining, the answer is "it depends". What if you want to pass a function pointer to `foo` somewhere?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The compiler chooses what it wants to do so we can't say what it will choose to do. That said, the function being `static` will not prevent it from being inlined; `static` functions are basically free functions with a different naming style and access to the class' private members.

Comment: They differ from free functions in one important respect: access to private members

Comment: @John ah yes, that is an important difference.

Comment: Doesn't a definition inside the class imply a request to inline anyway?

Answer (score 7):

A static member method has no `this` parameter, and can therefore only access static member variables.

It is distinct from whether the method is inlined or not. So the two are independent of each other.

The compiler decides if a method is going to be inlined or not. Your use of the keyword is merely a hint to the compiler.